# Why marking 1 check button is marking the second one either? Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to make a kind of a "table" with images and text on one side, and a check button next to each row on tabel. the tabel should have 2 columns. what I did was to create a class of a tabel, and ball it twich with 2 frames. the problem is, that when I mark a button, his opposite one gets marked too.

*****edited:
well, I solved it accidentally when trying to make al the button marked, I have 
added the marked line in the code below and it solved it but I don't know why. I will be happy for an explainment (markes as ****new)

images:

before:

http://prntscr.com/nbwr3x

after:

http://prntscr.com/nbwr9c

code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, side):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.root = root
        *******new: self.ver_list = [IntVar(value=1) for i in range(1, 202)]
        self.vsb = Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical")
        self.text = Text(self, width=40, height=20,
                            yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.im = Image.open("pic.png")
        self.tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)

        self.vsb.config(command=self.text.yview)
        self.vsb.pack(side="{}".format(RIGHT if side else LEFT), fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        if side:
            for i in range(1, 101):
                cb = Checkbutton(self, text="checkbutton #%s" % i, indicatoron=True, image=self.tkimage, compound=LEFT)
                cb.config(font=("Courier", 15))
                new***:  self.cb.config(variable=self.ver_list[i])
                self.text.window_create("end", window=cb)
                self.text.insert("end", "\n")  # to force one checkbox per line
        else:
            for i in range(101, 201):
                cb = Checkbutton(self, text="checkbutton #%s" % i, indicatoron=True, image=self.tkimage, compound=LEFT)
                cb.config(font=("Courier", 15))
                new***:  self.cb.config(variable=self.ver_list[i])
                self.button_list.append(cb)
                self.text.window_create("end", window=cb)
                self.text.insert("end", "\n")  # to force one checkbox per line


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    frame1 = Frame(root)
    frame2 = Frame(root)
    Example(frame1, 0).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    Example(frame2, 1).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    frame2.grid(row=0, column=1)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what was your code befor you add new lines?  Maybe you was using one `IntVar` for two `Checkbutton` - so they have work like one `Checkbutton`. Now every `Checkbutton` has own `IntVar` so you don't have this problem.

Comment: The same code without the ****new

Answer (score 1):

Try `print(cb["variable"])` and in old version you will see two variables with the same ID  - `!checkbutton`

The same with `!checkbutton2`, `!checkbutton3`, etc.

So first `Example()` creates local variables with some default names but later second `Example()` also create local variables with default names but it doesn't know that these names already exists.

This way two checkbuttons use variable with the same name.

In new code you create list with 202 `IntVar`s and they have unique IDs so every `Checkbutton` uses variable with unique ID.

```
    if side:
        for i in range(1, 101):
            cb = Checkbutton(self, text="checkbutton SIDE #%s" % i, indicatoron=True, compound=LEFT)
            cb.config(variable=self.ver_list[i]) #new***:  

            print(cb["variable"])

            self.text.window_create("end", window=cb)
            self.text.insert("end", "\n")  # to force one checkbox per line
    else:
        for i in range(101, 201):
            cb = Checkbutton(self, text="checkbutton #%s" % i, indicatoron=True, compound=LEFT)
            cb.config(variable=self.ver_list[i])#new***:  

            print(cb["variable"])

            self.text.window_create("end", window=cb)
            self.text.insert("end", "\n")  # to force one checkbox per line
```

Comment: I understood. Thanks alot for this answer!